# How to connect to applications hosted behind an application load balancer in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I followed [A Practical Guide to Deploying Microservices on AWS](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/a-practical-guide-to-deploying-microservices-on-aws-6a8ddd298f7e) to deploy an internal API in AWS ECS. However the guide fails to mention how to access the API via internet.

There are examples ([Access Private applications on AWS Fargate using Amazon API Gateway PrivateLink | AWS Compute Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/access-private-applications-on-aws-fargate-using-amazon-api-gateway-privatelink/)) on how to do this, if the app is behind a NLB, however this one is an ALB. Is there any such examples on how to access this internal api?

Comment: An *internal* API isn't supposed to be accessible from the Internet.  That's essentially what qualifies it as "internal."

Comment: For the purpose of this investigation, lets assume there is an external API that delegates requests to this internal API.